# Select Value Of CSV in MasterTable From Reference Table

Tags: sql, csv

Consider these two tables:

--Subscriber_File---

```
ID  GenreId  FileName

01      1,2       TestFile.pdf
```

--MasterGenre--

```
ID  Genrename

1      TEst1

2      Test2
```

When I issue this query, I'd like the result to be formatted as follows

```
Select * From Subscriber_File
```

```
ID  GenreId        FileName           GenreName

1       1,2          TestFile.pdf           TEst1,Test2
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL, Access, SQLite? You've got to put more effort into your question so as to help answerers.

Comment: You forgot, for instance, sybase :P

Comment: @DhruvalDave: Storing multiple values in a single field in a single row (as you are doing with GenreId on Subscriber_File) is a violation of First Normal Form. It should be avoided wherever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is not normalized. Specifically, in the one row for Subscriber_File, you have two facts in one place: the fact that the one entry is realted to both MasterGenre 1 and MaterGenre 2. What if they were related with three MaterGenres? What if 10? The code requited to associate your facts quickly escalates into an unmanageable mess.

The standard solution—when using relational database systems—is to normalize you data, such that each “repeating fact” is represented by one row in a table. (Google "database normalization" and you'll find thousands of articles on the subject. Really.) Here, you might end up with:

```
Table Subscriber
SubscriberId
FileName

(01, TestFile.pdf)

Table Genre
GenreId
GenreName

(1, Test1)
(2, Test2)

Table SubscriberGenre
SubscriberId
GenreId

(01, 1)
(01, 2)
```

At which point querying the data becomse trivial:

```
SELECT sub.SubscribeId, gen.GenreId, sub.FileName, gen.GenreName
 From Subscriber sub
  Inner join SubscriberGenre subgen
   On subgen.SubscriberId = sub.SubscriberId
  Inner join Gener gen
   On gen.GenreId = subgen.GenreId
```

This should produce the result set

```
(01, 1, TestFile.pdf, Test1)
(01, 2, TestFile.pdf, Test2)
```

Hmm, you’re still challenged with converting those two lines into the one with a “1,2” value. I’ll let someone else answer that; my main point is that without normalized table structures, you’ll have trouble getting anything done.

Comment: Yes Thanks a lot for Info.  but right Now i've to must do like given above.. Will you Please help...?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you approve of or agree with an answer (or a question), you shoud upvote them. (Similarly, you can downvote things you disagree with, though most people only do that if they strongly disagree with them.)